# FOSUserBundle / RegistrationController too few arguments

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm a new symfony user.
Today I updated symfony to version 3.4.
I had already installed `friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0@dev"`.

When I go on the registration page http://example.com/app_dev.php/register/  I get this message:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/beta.jostratennis.com/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php on line 195 and exactly 4 expected

```
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle dev-master 5884948
```

Where can I find the solution?

Comment: Can you add your routing.yaml and config/services.yaml?

Comment: please you can share your config.yml, routing.yml and services.yml ?. thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Lock your fos user bundle version in your composer.json

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*" 
# instead of
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev"
```

After that, you can update dependencies again, running

```
composer update
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it was issue for me.

Comment: Helped me, too!